# How do I use two dropdown menu instances from the same model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue where I think I have set things up correctly, however the results are alway nil.

Here's the three models:

```
public class FamilyMember
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }

    public virtual FamilyRelationship FamilyRelationship { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string fullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, surname);
        }
    }
}

public class RelationshipType
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Relationship Type")]
    public string relationshipType { get; set; }
    public virtual FamilyRelationship FamilyRelationship { get; set; }
}

public class FamilyRelationship
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FamilyMembers")]
    [Display(Name = "First Family Member")]
    public int familyMemberPrimary { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FamilyMembers")]
    [Display(Name = "Second Family Member")]
    public int familyMemberSecondary { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Relationship Type")]
    public int relationshipType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FamilyMember> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelationshipType> RelationshipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have successfully added data to `FamilyMember` and `RelationshipType` and the CRUD is working perfectly.

The problem is found in the Create Controller/View of `FamilyRelationship`. The dropdown works perfectly and shows the family members in the two associated menus and the relationship also shows on the `relationType` dropdown. However, when I click create all values are set to null.

**Create Controller:**

```
    // GET: FamilyRelationships/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.familyMember = new SelectList(db.FamilyMembers, "id", "fullName");
        ViewBag.relationship = new SelectList(db.RelationshipTypes, "id", "relationshipType");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: FamilyRelationships/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,familyMemberPrimary,familyMemberSecondary,relationshipType")] FamilyRelationship familyRelationship)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.FamilyRelationships.Add(familyRelationship);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(familyRelationship);
    }
```

**Create View:**

```
    @model FamilyTree.Models.FamilyRelationship

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>FamilyRelationship</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@

                    @Html.DropDownList("familyMember", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.familyMemberSecondary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("familyMember", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.relationshipType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("relationship", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.relationshipType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong and if possible provide an example to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList("familyMember"`

you need to use the actual property names most likely

`@Html.DropDownList("familyMemberPrimary"`

you'd also have to rename the viewbag property to match for the items to show up.. or use dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.familyMemberPrimary, (SelectList)ViewBag.familyMember , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

you also need to add a dropdownlist for familyMemberSecondary

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.familyMemberSecondary, (SelectList)ViewBag.familyMember , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This should get you pretty close..

```
@model FamilyTree.Models.FamilyRelationship

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>FamilyRelationship</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.familyMemberPrimary, (SelectList)ViewBag.familyMember, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyMemberPrimary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.familyMemberSecondary, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.familyMemberSecondary, (SelectList)ViewBag.familyMember, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyMemberSecondary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.relationshipType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.relationshipType, (SelectList)ViewBag.relationship, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.relationshipType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

make sure you re set your ViewBag properties after a failed POST

[**DotNetFiddle Example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3VMK8)

Comment: That's fantastic. Really appreciate your effort in helping with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. Remember Http is stateless. So you need to reload your dropdown data before returning to the view

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,familyMemberPrimary,familyMemberSecondary,
                                  relationshipType")] FamilyRelationship familyRelationship)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.FamilyRelationships.Add(familyRelationship);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

    //Let's reload the data for dropdown.
    ViewBag.familyMember = new SelectList(db.FamilyMembers, "id", "fullName");
    ViewBag.relationship = new SelectList(db.RelationshipTypes, "id", "relationshipType");

    return View(familyRelationship);
 }
```

**EDIT:** *As per comment*

> The values within the FamilyRelationship so familyMemberPrimary,
>   familyMemberSecondary and relationshipType have values of 0, where I
>   was expecting the id's of each of these would be passed over.

Because you are using `EditorFor` helper method for `familyMemberPrimary` property in your view. So if you are not filling a value in that input field, it is going to have default value(0 for int type)

If you want that property to be filled with your dropdown selection(of family members), you should give the dropdown name value as `familyMemberPrimary` so that when you post the form, model binding will set the selected option value to familyMemberPrimary property.

```
@Html.DropDownList("familyMemberPrimary", 
           ViewBag.familyMember as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
           htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: That is a good point, however that doesn't solve the issue as to why I am not getting any values.  No matter what I select from the three dropdown menus, the results are 0,0,0 and I can't seem to get the id values from each selection.

Comment: What are you not getting ? Your HttpPost action method's parameter is of type `FamilyRelationship` which property value is not coming properly ?

Comment: The values within the `FamilyRelationship` so `familyMemberPrimary`, `familyMemberSecondary` and `relationshipType` have values of 0, where I was expecting the `id`'s of each of these would be passed over. I'm not sure where in the code it's going wrong. I know I have made a mistake, just can't seem to see it.

Comment: You are using `EditorFor` helper method for `familyMemberPrimary` property in your view. So if you are not filling a value in that input field, it is going to have default value(0 for int type).

Comment: Thank you for your support on this. I wasn't using EditorFor, that line was commented out.  I will try your suggestion though.